# OOP PDO Query null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
class User {
  private $conn;
  private $table_name = "users";

  public $id;
  public $firstname;

  public function __construct($db){
      $this->conn = $db;
  }

   public function create(){
     $query = "INSERT INTO
              " . $this->table_name . "
              SET
              firstname = :firstname";

        $stmt = $this->conn->query($query);

        $this->firstname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->firstname));

        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $this->firstname);

        if($stmt->execute()){
          return true;
        }else {
          $this->showError($stmt);
          return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>
> Why my query is NULL?

---

When I make a var_dump to use everything goes well but I do not understand why my query is null

Comment: Do you mean OOP?

Comment: Ensure that you're properly connected to your DB. It's saying it can't call query on your $this->conn as it's not an object.

Comment: Did you pass the connection varibale on the constructor

Comment: Looks like database is not connected still.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: That `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(...))` line is going to make an absolute mess of your content. You should save any content as raw as possible, then escape it *if and when* it's necessary *for the context it's being presented in*. That is, for HTML, use HTML escaping. For JSON use JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You are running

```
$stmt = $this->conn->query($query);
```

That is incorrect and will fail as the query has a bindable parameter i.e. `firstname = :firstname`

You have to run

```
Prepare
bindParam
execute
```

In that order

Also this query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO" . $this->table_name . "
            SET firstname = :firstname";
```

When it does run, will change`firstname` in every row in that table to whatever is in `$this->firstname`

And it is not clear that you have actually set a value in there OR in the `$conn` property.

Comment: As well as the fact that `$this->firstname` is never set unless the OP is just not showing us this in the code

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Yea, I spotted that too, eventually

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://codeshare.io/5e3AeJ look at the rest of my code ! I changed my $ query variable but still have not fixed the bug

Comment: You are not passing the Database connection on the constructor so change this line. `$user = new User();` to `$user = new User($db);`